# Windows 10 freezes and Taskbar icons will not restore display

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, freeze, taskbar, restore

Windows 10 when I minimize an app and then work on something else the original app will not restore from the taskbar.Other times the display just freezes and nothing works.The only way to fix this is to ctrl+shift+esc which brings up task manager and then restart windows explorer. I have checked all display drivers etc and they are all up to date. Any clues?

Comment: This is on a Dell optiplex 990 ,windows 10 pro, build 10240

Comment: Test your file system, test your disks, test your RAM, try a fresh Windows install. As-is this is too broad (IMO), VTC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be any number of causes. The first thought that comes to mind is the paging file isn't writing/reading correctly. When you minimize a program/app, the data for it is written to the paging file in order to free actual RAM (this is what causes a slight delay when you switch between open applications). Then when you open/maximize the app, the data is read from the paging file and processed back to the RAM for use. It sound like the data either isn't being written correctly (or hasn't completed writing) or isn't being read correctly to reopen the application. 
A second thought is other software that is using a lot of your computer's resources. Does anything stand out in the task manager under CPU or memory usage when this is happening?

Comment: Looks like IAStorDataMgrSvc , Intel(R) Rapid Storage Technology is taking up a lot of cpu,will disable it and see if that fixes it this week.

Comment: That didn't do anything still locks up.

Comment: One other solution I've seen for this was that after being minimized, the app/program would re-open maximized, but like 2 feet to the side of the visible screen (literally 2 feet off the monitor). Try this:

Minimize the problem program/app. Click on it once as you would to re-open it. Hold your windows key, and tap your left or right arrow key 2-3 times. If it is opening off-screen, this will pull it back to the visible monitor.

Comment: That doesn't work, still trying to find out what exactly causes the problem.

Comment: Now happens on another laptop. still trying to determine when it occurs

Comment: Upgraded to rel 10586 and problem has disappeared(hopefully). System did not do an auto update so did a manual one.

Comment: Still have the problem even with latest 10586.   After i open and minimize a few different apps the task bar blanks and there is no response to maximize any apps.